source vertex has no outgoing edges in GcsTrajectoryOptimization
I'm working on a GcsTrajectoryOptimization project where I encountered INFO:drake:Source vertex 187 has no outgoing edges. after calling trajopt.SolvePath(source, target, options).
I'm not sure why this error came out and didn't find relevant info in drake's documents. I guess this problem arose because there was no edge connecting source and gcs_regions. But I built a quite simple environment and there should be outgoing edges. Could you please suggest how to check this error?


I suspect that your initial state is not inside any of your regions (if we confirm that's the case, then we should probably try to make this error message more clear).
To debug, I'd recommend drawing the graphviz of your trajopt problem, with e.g.:
import pydot
pydot.graph_from_dot_data(    
    trajopt.graph_of_convex_sets().GetGraphvizString(active_path=[])
)[0].write_svg("test.svg")


thanks!! I will try to inspect in this way
